# The many users of CGCC

Tags: discussion, users

**What are the stories behind your username and avatar?**

Some users' usernames and/or their avatars have a significance behind them. What about yours?

Comment: [The inspiration for this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sff-se)

Answer (score 33):

"caird coinheringaahing" comes from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118068/66833) Jelly answer. Given that the answer is written in Jelly (my primary language on the site), and the challenge is very much about the site, I thought that it'd be a fun, unique username that references the site.

[And it should be pronounced "cared co-in-hear-ing-aah-ing"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=56777627#56777627)

Fun fact, moving the space around in that answer leads to the following possible usernames:

```
ChartZ Belatedly
oppS,aback
reerects bespangling aachen
Erasmians cleptaahing
caird coinheringaahing
Dude coinheringaahing
```

I have changed my username (briefly) to both `ChartZ Belatedly` (during March 2021) and `Dude coinheringaahing` (August 2021), and I'm `reerects bespangling aachen` on the [CGCC Gaming](https://discord.gg/J2F8KTHBb4) Discord server.

During June, July and August 2022, my username was "Zion mycelia adamancy", as requested by emanresu A due to [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61443106#61443106) message in TNB:

> 6 hours ago, by Radvylf Programs
>
> > Well my Jelly encoder doesn't quite work yet, unless caird changed their name to ​Zion mycelia adamancy! and none of us noticed

---

As for my avatar, it is a picture of my adorable puppy, Patch. Over December/January, I put a Santa hat on him. During October, it is a picture of my other adorable puppy, Pepper, with a witch hat for Halloween, [courtesy of Radvylf](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62134487#62134487)

Comment: Ok I am dumb. "cared" is supposed to be an English word, not a phonemic representation.

Comment: You got a new username! What is the story behind this one?

Comment: @Wasif It was one of the other "possible usernames" that he or she could have changed to

Comment: @expressjs123 thanks for making me notice that

Comment: "over December/January"

Answer (score 25):

There's no story here. I'm just not creative.

Comment: "User user" when I click on your profile

Answer (score 16):

Mine has several meanings:

- Many of the answers here on CGCC are quite *traumatic* to read, and everything here is *digital*.
- *Digital Trauma* is the medical term for nose-picking.  I think a lot of us are figuratively picking our noses here, i.e. spending time asking/answering challenges for fun, when we should probably be focussing our talents elsewhere, e.g. paid employment or study.
- I decided on this handle shortly after recovering from a particularly nasty medical episode of uncontrolled nasal bleeding - caused by a botched deviated septum surgery, and not literal nose-picking!  4 ED visits, 1 ICU admission and several pints of transfused blood later, this is a tale I am happy to be able to tell.  Suffice to say, the term *Digital Trauma* was quite vivid in my mind at the time.

Answer (score 16):

*[Now in "Passed through way too many languages on google translate edition](https://gist.github.com/Lyxal/17421b5130fa202c15778e3acb4b5580)*

Wow, y'all with your usernames that actually have meaning.

I literally just spent 5 minutes typing random keys until I ended up with something I deemed "cool" and "ironic". Having said that, I did want to make sure the letters L and X were present (for maximum coolness) and that there was a name length of 5 (shorter names are more memorable, leading to hopefully more up votes).

Admittedly, Google once attempted to give it meaning... I placed it into google translate (using detect language) , and it spat out `Lyhal`, claiming it was in `Azerbaijani`. I repeated the process with lyhal and detect language... The result was `to solve` and the detected language was Arabic.

For the record, it is [**NOT**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=54384050#54384050) [pronounced](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54384051#54384051) [`licks-all`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56886098#56886098). That's just gross, weird and downright disgusting (screw you text-to-speech). It is supposed to be pronounced `likesal` (tts it and you'll hear what I mean). Okay say it with me now...

## Likesal

There you go. Now you know how to pronounce it properly.

Comment: whoops, I've been pronouncing it "licks-all" to myself all this time. oopsies

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I pronounce it more like "lie-xall"

Comment: You’ve changed your pfp

Answer (score 14):

`regexp` backwards.

Many of my previous online aliases have been obscure programming terms, backwards. This one is not quite as obscure, but it has two extra features that make it suitable:

- it contains `x`, which as we all know, is the [most expensive letter in the alphabet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDV7aA6arVo)
- it starts and ends with my initials

It's pronounced /pʰə̆ɡsɛˈgə/ or /pʰə̆ɡsɛˈgər/.

Comment: Here I am was pronouncing it /psiger/.

Comment: I never thought of `regexp` backwards when i saw your username ;O

Answer (score 11):

My username basically comes from my childhood when I loved to play [Puzzle Bobble series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle_Bobble). It's been my username of choice since I started activity on international online games and communities.

I also used to be a Kirby fan, so my avatar has always been a Kirby. I found out that "Bubble Kirby" is a thing a few years ago, so I changed my avatar to a picture of Bubble Kirby.

Not to be confused with the [GitHub organization called Bubbler](https://github.com/Bubbler), which made me append [a random number](https://xkcd.com/221/) to [my GitHub account](https://github.com/Bubbler-4).

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a new name for this site and couldn't come up with anything particularly clever. The last answer I had submitted was in x86 machine code under IBM PC DOS, and the frequently mis-attributed quote to Bill Gates about "[640KB ought to be enough](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2534312/the--640k--quote-won-t-go-away----but-did-gates-really-say-it-.html)" just popped into my head. So I just thought "haha, okay that'll work".

Answer (score 11):

I just used my first name when I joined Stack Exchange and never changed it.

It's a less common form of **Arnaud** (without an "L") but is however pronounced the same way, i.e. **\aʁ.no\** (and not **\aʁ.nɔld\** like "Arnold").

I went by the nickname "Axl" many years ago as the sysop of a BBS running on an Atari 520 ST during the pre-Internet era. (Yeah... Like the singer of a famous hard rock band from Los Angeles. :-p)

Comment: Hm... Axl Lily of the Pistols N Lilies?

Comment: @AndrewTheCodegolfer Yeah, something like that! ;)

Comment: Heh, thanks for clarifying that it is pronounced the same way as "Arnaud", even with the "L". I've been pronouncing your name wrong in my head all these years! I'll try to correct that. :-)

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 65 bytes

```python
my_name="Adam"
print(".".join(map(str,map(ord,my_name.lower()))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3HXMr4_MSc1NtlRxTEnOVuAqKMvNKNJT0lPSy8jPzNHITCzSKS4p0QHR-UYoOVLVeTn55apGGJghADIKaBzMXAA)

Comment: The real answer: My original username on the site was Adam because that's the name in the Google account I linked, but there is already an Ádam who is a regular user, which led to some issues in the SE Chat. I ended up changing it to point-separated Unicode values because I like how it looks like an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 10):

When I was seven or something my friends and I all had code names. Mine was `redwolf`. A few years later, I got a gaming console, and `redwolf` was obviously taken. I just stuck random numbers on the end, until I got `redwolf10105`.

I actually used this for a while; I did have a stack overflow account with that name, but I forgot my password.

When I was twelve or so, I got an idea: I thought I was *amazing* at web development (read: I could make a box turn different colors), so my friends and I decided to make a company. We called it Redwolf Programs.

Later, I registered a domain with that name, and used it for my various projects. Originally I did web stuff, but then game development and chat rooms seemed like more interesting projects. The "company" is gone, but my name has stuck :p

Comment: People from the future: It's "Radvylf" now because that's the closest available analog to "Redwolf" in the [Katlani](https://github.com/katlani/katlani) alphabet.

Comment: And those of you further in the future: It's "Rydwolf" now since I realized that's actually closer

Answer (score 9):

When I was 5, I gave myself and all my siblings nicknames. Beefy was the one I gave to myself and it evolved into Beefster by the time I was 12 and had an online presence. I see no reason to change it now with such a long-running history.

And no, it has nothing to do with muscles and no relation to Beefcake. It has more to do with the meat that comes from bovines.

My avatar is Verrick (from Legend of Korra) mashed up with Uncle Sam: "I want YOU to do the thing!" I made it in GIMP on a whim after being struck with the inspiration on a walk home from campus.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with muscles, does it mean you're made of beef, or that you like beef, or that you look like a cow?

Comment: I like beef. It is a tasty meat.

Comment: Ah, ok. That was the most likely of the three options I'd thought, but I was kinda hoping you were a cow :) Edit: Actually, *are* you a cow? If so, I deeply apologize; I did not mean to insult you in any way for your choice of food.

Answer (score 9):

Pi's my favorite number, it is a totally original play on "easy as pie" (hence why I have like 15 variations of my username around the web), and my avatar is literally the default Google one rotated 180°.

I'm not that creative. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Don't you mean your avatar is *rotated by π radians*? :-)

Answer (score 9):

My username has been around for far too long for me to remember the actual original inspiration.

My first real username was "galaxy_traveler" - my Minecraft username back in around grade 5 or so, when I created my account. I joined Code Golf under the alias James Smith, which was sort of an obsession of mine at the time (using extremely generic names as an "anonymous" name).

I changed my username to Alex L. sometime later, which is my real name, probably because I stopped using weird anonymous names everywhere (including my primary personal email - that got to be confusing, honestly).

The earliest record I can find of my presence as "HyperNeutrino" was in 2017 in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111591/68942) (mentioned both in the comments and in chat, although that chat profile is detached + deleted and the one I use right now was created later). That was probably around the same time I switched my Minecraft username to it as well (I had possibly a couple in between; I remember there was at least one).

---

The idea definitely came from my obsession with random area of STEM at the time, and theoretical physics was definitely one of those areas (being a theoretical physicist was one my potential future pathways for a while, but I later decided against it to pursue computer science 100%). I am not sure where the "Hyper" part came from. "HyperNeutrino" actually has no real meaning, although I was once fooled into think it existed by Jan Dvorak in [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36634573):

> A bineutrino is an excited bound state of two neutrinos that occurs once per year per galaxy and lasts about 10^-36 seconds. Normally they aren't useful, but a type-IV civilization is able to create a swarm of bineutrino collectors that can stabilize one temporarily until hopefully a third neutrino reacts with the existing bineutrino. The resulting trineutrino lasts much longer and is very likely to catalyze further collisions, creating a hyperneutrino, a particle the size of a small star.

---

The reason my name is "hyper-neutrino" now is because many people have small screen size or higher page zoom that causes my name to entirely disappear while in chat. This issue was mostly caused by my diamond, since previously my name could just barely fit most of the time, but the added space from the diamond caused it to just vanish. By using "hyper-neutrino", the hyphen creates a spot for breaking the line, so my name will instead show as "hyper", which is still not ideal, but is much better than it just disappearing altogether.

---

There isn't a particular story behind my avatar. It used to be a benzene ring, which I joined the site with, owing to my obsession with chemistry at the time. It actually stayed as that for quite a long period of time, until around a year ago when I changed it to K/DA All Out Akali's icon (League of Legends) since the skin line was just coming out and I really liked it (and I am / was an Akali main). Also, it wasn't too far off from my previous icon, since it was still a black square with a white symbol in the center, which is fairly unique (or at least, it was, but now lyxal is probably more well-known if one is to think about a pure white-on-black avatar).

I changed it a couple more times as well, though I cannot remember all of those changes. It was a picture of Eula from Genshin Impact for a while, but eventually I decided to change it a) to simplify it for recognizability (which was prompted by the room owner election, where "static username" and "static avatar" because campaigning points for consistent recognizability), b) to stop people from saying "haha anime girl" (Genshin Impact is a Chinese game, not Japanese, by the way, but it is still pretty much an anime game based on its art style and like, everything about it other than the actual nationality of the comapany that created it), and c) one person did mention that they thought I changed my pronouns as a result of making my profile image a female character. I have always been 100% a cisgender male, and I can understand why that would be misleading.

Thus, I decided to create a new profile picture that I would stick to to be a) recognizable, b) unique, and c) representative. I couldn't find anyone using the lambda symbol yet, and so, based on inspiration from Redwolf Programs's profile picture, I made it a monochromatic 16x16 pixel art image of a lambda symbol. It was originally purple-on-black, but I didn't like that as much as the current purple-on-white one, so I used this instead after switching between the two a few times.

Is it recognizable? I would say yes. Is it unique? In terms of the lambda symbol being unique, yes; the style is pretty much copied from Redwolf. Is it representative? Sort of? I am a programmer, after all, not just by hobby but field of study and profession. Do I know much about lambda calculus? Not nearly as much as I wish I did. I know the basics, but by no means am experienced.

---

TL;DR - there is a story behind these, but no particular significance behind either my name or my profile picture. In fact, entirely rebranding myself has been something I have considered many times, but I think I will wait until a notable change in my life to do something like that, and I don't know if that will happen or if I want that to happen. So, in case I change it, for the record, this is my current profile.

[image: hyper-neutrino's current CGCC flair]

Comment: Very long (and somewhat odd) story +1

Comment: haha anime girl :P

Answer (score 8):

###### Name

When I was like 11 or something I was just dabbling a bit in JavaScript and had gotten far enough to know what the data type containing text was called. I figured it would be clever to make the observation that usernames, being entirely arbitrary, don't necessarily reflect anything about the people who have them--never mind how little truth there is to that... And thus was born Unrelated String.

###### Avatar

The avatar I use on the rest of the network and virtually everywhere else is ultimately the portrait of Ryze from *League of Legends*, mangled beyond recognition by myself and a friend. On CGCC and in chat, however, [after](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59742047#59742047) the fateful events of [Cat Week](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58916971#58916971), I've sported 16 and counting hand-cropped anime profile pictures <s>as a reminder to society that my opinions are invalid</s>--at the time of writing, Sengoku Nadeko from the teaser visual for *Monogatari Series Off & Monster Season*, so if she isn't dramatically looking back at you with an ambiguous yet powerful expression, the number's wrong :P

Answer (score 8):

In my country/language, the term "polfosol" is a mockery for people who pretend to be knowledgeable, but actually don't have the slightest idea about the subject. e.g.

> -You shouldn't eat sausages. There are a lot of papers and scientific evidence that eating sausages will cause cancer.
> -Sure, *polfosol*.

And the profile picture just came after I decided to choose this username. Because you know, he was the best professor I have ever known in my life.

Answer (score 8):

When I first started coding, I started in Scratch with my friend. He gave us the username `segganew`, with a lowercase `s` (my "junk" email is still `segganew@gmail.com`). I decided to use it for a mobile game back when I just started having an online presence. My alliance ended up calling me `Seggan` (uppercase `S` because mobile) in chat, and I guess that name stuck. Before I used `Seggan`, I mostly had `Dan_the_Man`, although there were a few exceptions here and there. It is pronounced `S egg an`.

My avatar, if you zoom in, is a purple gas giant planet with a terrestrial moon orbiting it. I designed it in an online program that I forgot the name of.

Comment: I regret nothing.

Comment: Stegganography challenge is perhaps based on your username

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer what challenge?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25243/110681

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer ah

Comment: I'm wondering if you used https://spaceengine.org/ for the profile... though that's not exactly designing, so probably not.

Comment: @97.100.97.109, nope, wasnt space engine, it was some sort of online program

Comment: Is it just me or is your pfp just purely white?

Comment: @mousetail it is :P

Answer (score 7):

My username is a shortening of my old display name on Google+ (RIP), which I made about 6 years ago.

```
R    - Raghu
a    - all
ze   - the
time
```

My profile pic comes from the "Color Ghost" [Webcam Toy](https://webcamtoy.com/) effect. It still looks pretty cool, so I've kept it for a while now.

Answer (score 7):

<s>What can I say - I'm not creative.</s>  I'm still not very creative.

To avoid confusion, it should be pronounced "bread"

Comment: @PyGamer0 See above

Comment: user and emanresuA has a very similar avatars and a similar answers here. Isn't this a... friends? ;)

Answer (score 6):

My username "Davide' is just my actual name. Few months ago I was learning C (my first language) and signed up on SO to ask something. I think I didn't typed any username, just logged using my Google account.

I take this opportunity to change my username and add an avatar.

Apart from golfing in C and learning JavaScript, I only eat, sleep, listen to music (a lot of it) and cuddle two kittens of a flatmate. That's the reason why my username and avatar will be all about music.

My username is going to be **Sheik Yerbouti**. It comes from "The Sheik Yerbouti tango" by Frank Zappa. I chose this name because (apart from being the title of a nice guitar solo) it's kind of an actual name and it also encourages you to move, an invitation that can be interpreted in many ways.

As for the avatar I'll find a picture of music(?)

Comment: "I only eat, sleep, listen to music (a lot of it) and cuddle two kittens" Sounds like a great life :P

Comment: @user ahaha yes it sounds great, but I am actually a very lonely person struggling to build some real life skill. However there not much time to complain about life when you are busy shaiking yerbouti :D

Answer (score 6):

## Weasels

My username (Wezl) is Weasel spelled better and more recognizeable. Some weasel *facts* that may have influenced this decision.

- They're [adorable](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Mustela) (yes, this is a fact). A simple interweb search is enough proof.
- They're [evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed). I'm not necessarily evil, but it helps to have an evil avatar so I don't get held responsible for my actions.
- They [bring bad luck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel#Cultural_meanings). Not necessarily a fact, but in some cultures or superstitions this is true.
- They're underappreciated. This means I'm assisting the world by creating awareness, and as a bonus not many weasel-related usernames are taken.
- They're [stinky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustelidae#Characteristics). This did not influence my decision at all, but it doesn't hurt to mention it.

These may seem like reasons *not* to like weasels, but there's a reason people still have cats as pets (weasels aren't often pets because they're wild and love to kill...fingers). In fact, weasels are kind of like cats in a squirrel-sized body.

Some of these traits can be summed up in this hopefully-not-copyright-infringing clip:
[image: weasels!]

EDIT: Now I realize that to truly show my devotion, I must also change my pfp. This is it currently, though I change it a lot:

[image: Ermine/Weasel 16x16 picture]

Comment: They may be adorable, but I think being evil, bringing bad luck, and stinking are pretty good reasons not to appreciate weasels.

Answer (score 6):

**My username**

"sporeball" was essentially generated by brute force. I wanted something simple yet decently interesting, but I'm terrible at coming up with good ideas, so a couple of years ago I wrote a little bit of JavaScript to make up names for me.

The code first populates an array with 114 words I picked out by hand (`star`, `rice`, `cloak`, `ocean`, `pants`, `knuckle`, `coffee`, etc.) Then, at the push of a button, it picks two random words from the array and concatenates them! Simple as that.

After a few minutes of clicking, the string `sporeball` came out, and the rest is history.

**My avatar**

In January of this year, a friend of mine drew a picture of me in my signature purple cat costume (yes, I have a cat costume) as a present for my 17th birthday. I loved it so much that I immediately asked her if I could use it as my new avatar,* and she agreed.

My friend replaced the drawing's original white background with that nice lavender one, a hex code chosen for its similarity to my website's background color, and I cropped the drawing, which was originally from the waist up, to a 400x400 headshot. Closer to March, I asked if I could have it updated to reflect my change from rectangular glasses to circular ones; this new version, which also depicts slightly longer hair, is the one currently in use on this site.

<sup>* My previous avatar was created with the [Snout Folk image maker](https://picrew.me/image_maker/65495) on Picrew.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I watch Alan Becker and eat bagels.

2022 update:
Grand Bagel in katlani.

2023 update:
Alan Bagel in english.

2024 update:
Bread + ai generated image

Comment: +1 just because Alan Becker

Answer (score 6):

My username is a randomly generated one from my head. I just thought of "Dial" and "Frost", and put them together!

My pfp was from @lyxal ;)

Oh and yes I do love <s>burning</s> freezing tags on SO. I mean I *do* have `frost` in my name :3

I do love the cold too in winter, another great reason why I picked `frost`.

Answer (score 5):

My username? Well I just happen to see this mathematical expression *everywhere* in my math textbook im getting tired of this expression this is boring i want to get out of this! I hate 2x-1 2x-1 is bad I want to kill him!!!

And then, all of a sudden, I decided that I can use this as my username to make others feel bored like me as well! *evil laughs*

As for my avatar, I want to change it someday, but not now. :P

Comment: +1 for being evil. Not sure why you don't want people to view your profile, though, it's a good way to make other people hate 2x-1 too

Comment: Let's kill 2x-1!

Comment: It looks like 2x-1 has...disappeared. @SheikYerbouti, what did you do?

Comment: He went on vacation. He told me to let everybody know that he is all right and will come back after he has found himself. What? ...no it's just tomato sauce from lunch. *Sheit!*

Comment: I saw someone pretending to be him [2x-1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/100947/2x-1)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of years ago, I got into reading a Russian knock-off of Harry Potter which one of my friends recommended to me (the book was actually really well-written, still one of my all-time favourites). During one of the chapters, a noticed a character with the name Varsus, suspiciously similar to that friend's online nickname Varsis. When I told him about it, he confirmed that he just slightly changed that character's name to create his nickname. I responded to that with doing the same - taking one of the character's name Dionius and simplifying it to Dion. I've been using it ever since, often wrapping it in 8s to make 8Dion8 when just Dion wasn't available. As for my pfp, it's a random year-old photo of me that a friend took on a trip to the countryside. I've often also been using a frame from [this meme](https://images.app.goo.gl/mjpwt4QWU56zqm3b6) when I didn't want my actual photo on display, or a [Bill Wurtz thumbnail](https://ibb.co/P9qxWG9) on my Discord.

Comment: Вы знаете русский?

Comment: @Danis for what? :P

Comment: Honestly I didn't expect to see you here. Weird. Yes, I'm just climbing over all the links. ;)

Answer (score 5):

It’s just my name + surname with all vowels removed. Boring…
The profile pic is some doodle I did many years ago, but I like it so it stuck.

Answer (score 5):

Oktupol is the german spelling for octupole, a magnetic field created by eight electric charges; four dipoles or two quadrupoles.

I started using that name while experimenting with computer networks as a teenage child. I was interested in physics back then; when I needed to come up with host names for some virtual machines, I named them Monopol, Dipol and Quadrupol because I just read about those in a book.

Eventually I hosted my first own website, and taking up on the scheme I established previously, I bought the domain "oktupol.de" and started using the name "oktupol" for myself everywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

My username isn't really anything special, it's just my hair color. My profile picture came from an offhanded comment from Wzl about needing to see a cat with a ಠ_ಠ face.

Comment: Also, as of the posting of this comment it has a Ukrainian flag overlay in support of the [war in Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine).

Comment: You may want to clarify that you're in support of Ukraine, not in support of the war itself lol

Comment: ^ what he said :|

Answer (score 5):

My username is Aiden Chow. I mean, it's pretty obvious where it came from... I obviously used an AI to randomly generate names until I found one that I liked.... jk jk LOL. It's literally my real name, nothing much to it. You can tell I put so much thought and effort into my username XD.

As for my pfp, I drew it years ago when Google Hangouts still had a [Draw Feature](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/send-drawings-to-friends-with-google-hangouts-on-the-web/) (rip draw feature, you will forever be missed...). My friend and I were basically just sending random doodles to each other, and I noticed that one of my scribbles looked vaguely like a face. So I drew in the eyes, put in the mouth, and boom, my pfp.

Answer (score 4):

`ophact` is a randomly generated 6-character long string which came from a short piece of JavaScript code I wrote, a sort of "random competition" for JavaScript. It was the only readable word that came out, and has the sort of tone of "oh, fact?"

Answer (score 4):

I was walking around one day, thinking about what my username should be. I wanted something pseudo-English sounding, but not really meaning anything. So Makonede randomly popped into my head for some reason.

TL;DR: Literally no backstory.

Also, in case you've been living under a rock, my profile picture is my Minecraft character.

Answer (score 4):

My real name sounds very similar to "mouse" and since I'm a big fan of both real mice and computer mice. Most people online and IRL just call me Mouse.

I added tail just so that my username is at least 8 characters, the minimum on many sites. However, since I switched to wireless mice I may need to change it to remain accurate.

My profile picture is a stylized mouse.

Answer (score 4):

You might know me as the creator of the 2-D esolang [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle). I'm genderfluid so my pronouns vary on a day-to-day basis (or sometimes even more frequently than that), but xe/xem is a safe default if you don't have a chance to ask me or if I don't/can't respond.

I created the username `bbrk24` when I was in fourth grade, originally for an email account, but I've used it in many other places since. It contains the initials of my deadname, but it doesn't bother me.

In 2020, I started having more conversations online compared to in-person, for some reason. People tried to come up with various ways to say that consonant group out loud. The one that stuck best was *Beberka*, from someone reading "b-b-r-k" in his native language as "be-be-er-ka". I say it as [bɛ⁠ˈberka] (original) or [bə⁠ˈbeɹ̈kʰə] (more Englishy), roughly. My username on Discord is Beberka for that reason.

My usual profile picture here comes from Discord. For a while, I just had the default profile picture on Discord. At some point, one of my friends started sending a bunch of gradients and people were claiming them for profile pictures, so I did too. I set it as my profile picture here because someone in TNB said they confused me for [user](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user). For pride month, I've added a genderfluid *symbol* to my pfp, since I can't exactly combine the *flag* with the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

<s>My username is just my real name, Jacob.</s>

My name's **NOODLE MAN!!!** From now on you will call me **NOODLE MAN!!!**

My PFP is a self portrait I drew a year ago, might update it at some point though.

Comment: **NOODLE MAN NOODLE MAN**

Comment: Jacob, I'm not sure you would want to be made out of food...

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian Who's Jacob? This is **NOODLE MAN!!!** 

Comment: @noodleman you're Jacob.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian We don't talk about that guy here

Answer (score 3):

I created my username in 2012 when I was in Year 2 of NUS High School (roughly equivalent to US 8th grade), in the same process where I became a *My Little Pony: Friendship Is Magic* (MLPFIM) fan and created the pony version of myself.

[image: Parcly and Spindle]

At the time one of my main interests was organic chemistry, and I wanted a name for the pony based on some organic compound. My first choice was Paracet from paracetamol, but it didn't sound natural enough to me. I eventually found [paclitaxel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paclitaxel) – a chemotherapeutic drug that famously took 30 years after discovery to market and famously was the target of a [total synthesis race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paclitaxel_total_synthesis) in the early 1990s, just before I was born – and transformed the word to Parcly Taxel, complete with [an R I don't pronounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English). (The name is pronounced park-ly tax-səl, and far too many ponies think at first that the first name is *Parsley*.)

[image]

Eventually I became a vector graphics artist drawing MLPFIM stuff, both canon characters and original characters. At the same time I developed tools to help with the art, which evolved into my first Git repository called [Kinross](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Kinross) and the principal storage for my art called [Selwyn](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Selwyn). These "unusual" names in turn grew into one of my traditions: every Git repository I create must be named after a real-world location. ([Shinjuku](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Shinjuku), [Malibu](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Malibu), [Shibuya](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya), [Skopje](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Skopje)…)

[image: 92, Uranium – I did a "periodic table of ponies" project from 2020 to 2021]

[image: Six Alicorns. Parcly is, in my backstory, on par with MLPFIM's canon royalty]

Parcly's backstory developed alongside the art. In August 2013 she became a wish-granting genie. She then gained a windigo companion called Spindle in late 2015 – the ghostly horse in the first picture of this answer. I have been regularly commissioning others to draw pictures of Parcly as well.

[image: By Beardie]

Although MLPFIM is considered part of the furry fandom, it took until 2021 for me to draw more general furry art. I created my own furry characters; my "fursona" (that represents myself in the furry world) is a female tiger genie called Tori Taxel, whose species is also my Chinese zodiac sign. (I am a Chinese Singaporean after all.) Her husband is a chimeric dullahan called Hearth Taxel.

[image: By Arztin. Tori being a taur, this also plays on my real-life Western zodiac sign]

[image: By A-Lovy]

---

The "bat in a hexagon" avatar I use alongside the Parcly Taxel name is the [cutie mark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258642) of a [bat pony](https://derpibooru.org/tags/bat+pony) form of Parcly. Fluttershy became one in an MLPFIM episode, and her cutie mark changed from three butterflies to three bats; this change is sometimes emulated with original character bat ponies, including here.

[image]

The background of my avatar is RGB `#230F38`. This colour and the three colours in Parcly's cutie mark (exactly the same across normal and bat pony versions) are also used in the logos of many of my Git repositories, giving a common theme.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, just using my nick name.

Answer (score 2):

My profile pic is the default.

AndrewTheCodegolfer is the third name in a line of "andrewthe[thing]" names that I have had, the line beginning with andrewtheredditor and andrewthediscorder.

Answer (score 2):

Okie, because uh, replacement for my old name `edison1119` because security sucks.

My pfp is niko because niko is god.( from game *Oneshot*)

My pfp was my facebook pfp since I associated using it.
After I joined CGCC, I decided to change my pfp.

chat pfp comes from cat girl/boy week.

**meow**

Answer (score 2):

My username is an ancient relic from when my dad made my first Hotmail account before at least 2007. Ever since I've consistently used this username for everything. Since my real name is a hellish mess of a Chinese romanization, most people don't realize that it's just my first name with `big` prepended to it. Besides, most people don't know how to parse the `hsuan` part of it and just call me `bigy /bɪg.i/ "biggie"` in voice chat lol

I don't have a "set" profile picture, I just switch my profile pictures whenever  I find a good one somewhere on the internet. My current profile picture is a cutout of a face drawn by [@TheRealTrampy](https://twitter.com/TheRealTrampy/status/1344377385551060993) on Twitter of Thomas-ized members of the LNER A4 class (since a fictional member of the class, Spencer, appears in the show).

It also somehow manages to mimic my facial hair, so that's a bonus.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`oeuf` simply means `egg` in French, and it sounds pretty similar to the Roblox dead sound (`oof`), so I thought at the time that it would be funny to use it as my username.

As for the profile picture, it is an ASCII art drawing on a rabbit I found on [asciiart.eu](https://asciiart.eu). It was made by Linda Ball. I took the ASCII art, then use an online ASCII-to-image tool to turn it into an image. ([I believed it was this one](https://onlineasciitools.com/convert-ascii-to-image))

For the reason why I chose a rabbit, I used to play a mobile game called `Tsuki's Odyssey`, in which the main character, also called `Tsuki`, came back to his hometown from the crowded city life to start a calm life. Think of it like Animal Crossing, but on mobile phones.

Even though this game bores the hell out of me, it pretty much influences my username choice. If not because I like the name `oeuf` more, I could have chosen `tsuki` as my new username, as that's my username on many social platforms (or anywhere that has an account system).

Comment: Why isn’t it the proper spelling _œuf_?

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I never know how it's supposed to be pronounced, so I just go with my interpretation of how it should be pronounced.

Answer (score 2):

My pfp contains the image of Sophie Germain, it is nothing more than everything to me... I wish sometimes I could go back in time and tell her, that I am obsessed with her, and my love and respect for her will stay regardless of the time. That's all to say.

Long live [Imtiaz Germain primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258817/imtiaz-germain-primes)!

Edit: I removed her picture and now it's mine here

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, none of my work is ever done, thus the name.

My avatar was generated by a Scratch program that was not shared.

Answer (score 1):

### My name was a random string of words (The Empty String Photographer) somewhat related to programming that was very clever.

[image: Monkey on stage]

### For the profile picture, I like monkeys, so I took a nice shot of a plush toy using portrait mode on Iphone.

> [image]
>  
>  You monster! You made monkey sad!

Comment: … you change your name often

Answer (score 1):

My username is my initials.

My profile picture is some random whole-white image I found on my computer (problably from `mspaint.exe`)

Answer (score 1):

Username: Like user, I'm just not very creative.

Icon: It's my default identicon, edited to permanently keep my Winter Bash 2022 hat.